# How do I remove permission to specific user using setfacl

Tags: linux, permissions, centos-6, acl

I just executed the following command

```
setfacl -m user:userXXX:r /home/userYYY/private/
```

now I see

```
$ ll /home/userYYY/private/     
total 32                                            
drwx------+  5 userYYY quant   512 Sep  5 03:26 ./ 
drwxr-xr-x  41 userYYY quant 32768 Sep  5 12:49 ../
```

1. Does this little `+` the result of it ?
2. How do I remove permission to `userXXX`

Answer (score 17):

The following should do the trick :

```
setfacl -x u:userXXX home/userYYY/private/
```

And as far as I know, where ACL are enabled, a + sign is shown.

Answer (score 3):

1. yes
2. use command like this:

   setfacl -m user:userXXX:-r /home/userYYY/private/

or remove user at all

```
setfacl -x user:userXXX /home/userYYY/private/
```

Comment: I still have the `+` I found `setfacl -b /home/userYYY/private` removes it (removes all ACL perm stuff)

Comment: IMHO you have it (if you use -m) because it keep record of the user, but w/o any rights

Comment: yes just wanted to remove all trace of it